# How am I supposed to find information about RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been recently asked to take part in a web service project. They use Ruby on Rails, and I have found it extremely hard to learn.

The problem is that Ruby is a dynamic programming language with type information hided. I understand that this is a one way to program. What I don't understand, however, is why this type-hiding extends to the documentation.

I haven't been able to find any information about method return types or parameter types in [the rails api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

An example. When doing migrations, we use `create_table` method.

```
create_table :post do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.string :title
  t.string :text
  t.string :image
  t.integer :category_id
  t.date :date_available

  t.timestamps
end
```

There is that `t`. I don't want you to tell me what `t` is. I want to know where I can find out what it is. I want to know all about what methods it has, where these `string`, `integer` and `date` come from.

Now I have to spend my time reverse-engineering rails code and finding ambiguous tutorials on the Internet. Is there a single place to find the return types and the parameter types of all rails classes. And the constants. And everything.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html will explain migrations to you. I'd recommend learning about the basics of both Rails and Ruby before trying to make sense of a bunch of code you don't understand. (e.g. learn about flow control, blocks, procs, lambdas, typing, etc)

Comment: This seems like more of a rant than a question, could you clarify your requirements?

Comment: @fergusq, I'd recommend reading Black's Grounded Rubyist book. It's an awesome book, and very well-written. It'll help you.

Comment: `string`, `integer` and `date`, those are the types for your table columns that you or someone else on the project specified, you don't really need to reverse engineer Rails you just need to start there [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: @dinjas, I know about migrations and ruby flow control. Thing is that I'm unsure how to use the methods I don't know about. I know that they are column types. They are different for different databases (such as postresql and sqlite). How do I know which column types in which specific forms I must use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_table` is just a method. You'd find documentation for it in any of the locations for automatically generated method-level documentation for Rails. Such as:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table

The `|t|` is a block parameter, in a block you are passing to the `create_table` method, that the `create_table` method will then call with one parameter. If you don't understand how blocks work in ruby, you will definitely have an easier time if you read up on that. It's not specific to Rails, it's part of the ruby language.

So what type of object will `create_method` pass to the block argument?  The place you'd find this documented is in the `create_method` documentation, but indeed it does not seem to tell you. Other methods that take blocks may be more likely to be documented to tell you exactly what they'll pass (if it's not obvious), but it is a little bit annoying that it's not documented here.

With *this particular* method, it's kind of an implementation detail what class the `|t|` is -- what matters is what you can do with it. Which is actually a key to the ruby philosophy of "duck typing" in general, what matters is what you can do with an object, not what class it is. But I agree that knowing what class it is -- even if it's basically an internal class that you'll never instantiate yourself, as it is in this case --  makes it a lot easier to find documentation explaining exactly what you can do with it.  If I were writing the documentation for `create_method`, I would have documented that. But I wasn't.

I'm sorry in an SO answer we can only answer your questions, and not change Rails documentation or the nature or the ruby language or the ruby community's common practices to be more like you or I might prefer.

In this case, people figure out what you can do with the `|t|` from the documentation above for `create_method`, or from the [Rails migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).  The Rails Guides are pretty good for getting an overall picture of how various components of Rails work.  But they do assume an audience that already knows ruby as a language, and is familiar with the web and programming in general.

As it happens though, we're in luck, the Rails Migration Guide *does* tell us what that object is...

> For more details and examples of individual methods, check the API documentation. In particular the documentation for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements (which provides the methods available in the change, up and down methods), ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition (which provides the methods available on the object yielded by create_table) and ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table (which provides the methods available on the object yielded by change_table).

So that's what the `|t|` is, an ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition. (And perhaps you want to submit a pull request to Rails to add this bit of info to the method-level documentation of `create_table` etc themselves)

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition` has got a tiny bit of automatically generated documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html  . Additionally, I'd guess that every individual database type (mysql vs postgres etc) has different concrete implementations of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition`

But there isn't actually much there. As I said, in practice most developers don't really need to know more than what you can do with it as documented elsewhere. But I do understand your desire to know exactly what it is and what it does. Diving into the source is what most Rails developers would do at this point (or have done before to figure out exactly what class the object is, perhaps using a debugger).
Most automatically generated ruby documentation, like the ones we've been looking at, include a link on every method to view source for that method, right inline with the documentation. I use it a lot, sometimes the source easily answers whatever question I had the English-written documentation didn't (and sometimes it doesn't).

I understand you don't like that situation, I'm sorry I can't change reality for you in an SO answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the API docks for Rails. You can find the source code and definition of the api.

For the specific case of the "create_table" method. take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table. It'll explain that this method takes a block, returning SQL.

Comment: The dock page for `create_table` is fine, but for example `respond_to`-page gives no information about types. And I really don't want to read much Rails' source code to be able to use it.

Comment: @fergusq: "And I really don't want to read much Rails' source code" - you don't need to. Just grab a good rails book and you should be good to go. I seldom find myself going to read the code itself, documentation is usually enough.